# How will the Predator deal with the remaining weapons​ if their owner dies?

Tags: alien-franchise, predator-series, alien-vs.-predator, alien-vs.-predator-requiem

I will take the Predator Wolf as the sample. In *Alien vs Predator: Requiem*, we can saw that Predator Wolf was assigned​ to neutralize the Predalien Queen and finally they both die together in a nuclear bomb.

So, I wonder if the Predator dies on a mission, their remaining weapon will used by the other Predators​? We can saw that Predator Wolf have a lot of weapons​ and mask. Will they be passed down to the other Predators​?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## They use the dead pedator’s weapons (in case when needed)

In Alien v. Predator Requiem,

> when the Wolf Predator explores the crashed Predator ship, ***he picks up a dead Predator’s shoulder cannon and attaches the cannon to his other shoulder***. This is the first time, a Predator in any movie has been able to use dual shoulder cannons at the same time.
>
> <sub>Source: [here](https://www.avpgalaxy.net/predator/weapons/)</sub>

Since this is the only occurrence (that I can think of) where one Predator clearly does something with another Predator’s weapons, a plausible conclusion is “**they reuse the dead predator’s weapons**”

Comment: You're right though..